# TcpClient.Read read wrong value from TcpClient.Write?

Tags: c#

Hello I think my server reads wrong value from TcpClien.Write it should be 52(length byte array at the moment I sending it), but at server side when I look at size in TcpClient.Read it's allways 8192. What I'm doing wrong?

My Client:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
        NetworkStream serverStream;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Multiline = true;
            msg("Client Started");
            label1.Text = "Client Socket Program - ";

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Send();
        }

        public void msg(string mesg)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + mesg;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clientSocket.Connect("192.168.1.109", 8888);

            label1.Text = "Client Socket Program - Server Connected ...";
        }
        private void Send()
        {
            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            XElement outXML =XElement.Load("test.xml") ;

            byte[] outStream = ConvertXmlToByteArray(outXML, Encoding.UTF8);

            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
        }
        byte[] ConvertXmlToByteArray(XElement xml, Encoding encoding)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Encoding = encoding;
                settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true; // No prolog
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
                {
                    xml.Save(writer);
                }
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My Server

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
            TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
            int counter = 0;

            serverSocket.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Server Started");

            counter = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                counter += 1;
                clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Client No:" + Convert.ToString(counter) + " started!");
                handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
                client.startClient(clientSocket, Convert.ToString(counter));
            }

            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    //Class to handle each client request separatly
    public class handleClinet
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket;
        string clNo;
        public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo)
        {
            this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
            this.clNo = clineNo;
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
            ctThread.Start();
        }
        private void doChat()
        {
            int requestCount = 0;
            requestCount = 0;

            while ((true))
            {
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[(int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

                Console.Write(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize.ToString());

                XElement inXML = ConvertByteArrayToXml(bytesFrom);
                inXML.Save("jest2.xml");

                //XMLSave(dataFromClient);

            }
        }
        //private void XMLSave(string inner)
        //{

        //    XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        //    XmlDoc.Load("jest.xml");
        //    XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = XmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
        //    XmlNode nextNode = XmlDoc.CreateElement("root");
        //    nextNode.InnerText = inner;

        //    XmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(nextNode);

        //    XmlDoc.Save("jest.xml");
        //}
        XElement ConvertByteArrayToXml(byte[] data)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
            {

                return XElement.Load(reader);
            }
        }
        private byte[] RemoveNulls(byte[] DataStream)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DataStream.Length - 1; i++)
            {

                if (DataStream[i] == 0x00) DataStream[i] = 0x01;
            }
            return DataStream;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NetworkStream.Read` returns an integer which tells the number of read bytes.

> Hello I think my server reads wrong value from TcpClien.Write it should be 52(length byte array at the moment I sending it

Incorrect. TCP is a stream based protocol. That means that TCP can split up your message however it likes. It can send a couple of bytes at a time, merge two messages into one etc.

You'll therefore have to implement some kind of message detection in your code. There are two ways that are usually used:

1. Introduce a header that contains the number of bytes that the message is
2. Use a delimiter at the end of the message

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are throwing away the information about the actual number of bytes read, and use the buffer size instead. You use the entire buffer, although it's only partially filled with data.

The `Read` method returns the number of bytes that was actually read from the stream.

```
int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);
Console.Write(bytesRead);
```

Furthermore, you have to repeatedly call the `Read` method, as it doesn't have to return the entire stream at once. When the stream is read to the end, the `Read` method returns zero.

Related: [TcpListener truncating byte array randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686583/tcplistener-truncating-byte-array-randomly/9686752)